# Why is SST != SSR + SSE

Tags: python, statistics, linear-regression

I'm trying to create a function that shows the SST, SSR & SSE of a univariate linear regression equation like so,

```
@staticmethod
def fitEstimation(y, y_pred):
        y, y_pred, y_bar = np.array(y), np.array(y_pred), np.array(y).mean()
        
        SST = ((y-y_bar)**2).sum()
        SSR = ((y_pred-y_bar)**2).sum()
        SSE = ((y_pred-y)**2).sum()
        
        return SST, SSR, SSE, (SSR/SST)
```

When I call,

`fitEstimation(y=[1,2,3], y_pred=[1,2,4])` I get the output `(2.0, 5.0, 1, 2.5)`. which is against the rule of SST = SSR + SSE because `2.0 = 5.0 + 1` is false; am I missing something fundamental about this or just doing it wrong?

Comment: How do you get the predictions? The rule `SST = SSR + SSE` doesn't apply if you don't have optimal estimators.

Comment: The predictions are out of a model built by using the Least Squares Regression method of calculation. Could you define the purview of an optimal estimator please?

Comment: In the case of least squares, the optimal estimators are the betas (coefficients) giving you the minimum total residual squares. In your example, you have the actual values `[1, 2, 3]` -- the simplest regression model you can fit to this with no predictors is the mean model (i.e. y_pred = [2, 2, 2]). If you add variables, it should do at least as good as this one. But your predictions are worse than the mean model in terms of sum of squares of residuals. So it is quite likely that your coefficients are not optimal.

Comment: Gotcha, ```y_pred = [2, 2, 2]``` yields me better coefficients. So now the conclusion becomes that the coefficients are not decent, which means the linear relationship is not captured properly or the relationship is not linear at all! Can we then infer that the relation ```SST = SSR + SSE``` will only hold true if the abs(correlation coefficient) of the variables yields near 1 results? Sorry if I'm wrong, just learning.

Comment: Not necessarily. If you fit a linear regression model and find the optimal coefficients, you should get SST = SSR + SSE even if you have a nonlinear relationship or weak relationship. The optimal coefficients can be derived either analytically or using gradient descent. I think your method is not giving you the optimal coefficients there.